# Is XAMPP faster than running LAMP in WSL on Windows 10?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, windows

I've been using Local by Flywheel for my local dev environment but recently it started acting weird so I decided, that since I'd finally learned a decent amount of CLI, maybe I should try just using WP-CLI and LAMP installed on WSL for Windows 10.

Well [[I've run into a bunch of issues]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314106/trying-to-install-wordpress-on-wsl-windows-10-and-running-into-issues-with-wp-c) and I'm almost ready to throw in the towel. So I was thinking about using Xampp instead.

Is Xampp a virtual machine? Running LAMP in WSL isn't a virtual machine right? I know Local by Flywheel is a virtual machine which is part of why it's a bit slow sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP is not a virtual machine, it's a local server, and is excellent for local WP development, however attempting to use WP-CLI takes some more steps, detailed here: https://lmilosis.wordpress.com/2017/11/26/19/

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful. I've previously used MAMP before using Local and that's a virtual machine right? 

Also, would you happen to know what the performance of a LAMP in WSL is versus a XAMPP?